# How to create new Flow type having all properties of existing type but optional

Tags: javascript, flowtype

I have a type `State` in which all fields are required:

```
type State = {
  title: string,
  items: [],
  isActive: boolean,
};
```

I need to create a *new type* with all properties the same as in `State` but not required:

```
type StateUpdater = {
  title?: string,
  items?: [],
  isActive?: boolean,
};

// ({title: 'hello'}: State) — INVALID
// ({title: 'hello'}: StateUpdater) — OK
```

How can I implement this similarly to the following Flow pseudocode?

```
type StateUpdater = State.mapKeyValue(() => typeKey?: typeValue)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [$Shape](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/utilities/#toc-shape) utility:

```
type State = {
  title: string,
  items: [],
  isActive: boolean,
};

type StateUpdater = $Shape<State>;
```

> `$Shape` Copies the shape of the type supplied, but marks every field optional.